# React paste eventListener calling custom function uses initialized variable value instead of updated value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a input field with a 'paste' eventListener attached. The eventListener function should handle a state variable.
However, the handling function always uses the initialized value of my state variable instead of the updated one.

I have made [this snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-wescoff-oklqv?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate the problem.

Usage:

1. Paste some text into the input field. In the console, you should see `Variable not set yet`
2. Click on the button `Set variable`
3. Paste some text again into the input field. Console should now print `Variable set!!` but is still prints `Variable not set yet`

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `onPaste` event.

```js
<input onPaste={handlePaste} placeholder="paste here" />
```

```js
const handlePaste = () => {
    console.log("pasted text", customVariable);
  };
```